# What is the signficance of the _ seen in several variable names in ActionScript?

Tags: actionscript

I'm new to actionscript and I have noticed that many variable names in actionscript begin with an _ and I was wondering what the significance of it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Private variables in Actionscript tend to have a _ in front of them. Then you have getter/setters without the _ to give them public access.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably seeing a [naming convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identifier_naming_convention) being used.  There's no special significance from a language perspective.

Comment: I figured it was a naming convention I wanted to know what it meant tho.

Comment: @Anton That's why I included the link, so you could understand why naming conventions are significant.  However, from a language perspective, it is insignificant.

Answer (score 2):

it is true, that in JavaScript, people used _ to denote "don't touch this value", since controlling access level in JavaScript is quite tricky ... making a variable really unaccessible from outside is quite a pain in the a** ...

in ActionScript 2.0 and 1, there is absolutely NO rule ... :D ... for example in class `MovieClip`, in ActionScript 2.0, there you have properties like `_x`, and `_y` ... yet the best thing is `focusEnabled` vs `_focusrect`, both booleans, one determining, whether the clip can be focused, the other whether it has a yellow rectangle, when focused ...

either this is really related to some stuff coming from the flash players insides, or it is just random ... note that there is `_global`, `_root` and `_accProps` and apart from that, it only appears on properties of `TextField`, `MovieClip` and `Button` ...

`__` (two underscores) denotes magic in the flash player ... `__resolve` is quite a magic method ... and `__proto__` is a magic property, if you will ... but also, this is not very consistent everywhere ...

now when it comes to ActionScript 3.0, the whole API does not use any underscores ... many people, including me, chose to denote `private`, `protected` and `internal` variables with `$`s and `_`s ... but this is a completely arbitrary naming convention that should make the code readable and prevent naming collisions ...

greetz

back2dos

Answer (score 2):

It would be possible to write

```
class Hello{
  private var x:Number;
  public function get x():Number{...}
  public function set x(value:Number):void{...}

  protected var y:Number;
  public function get y():Number{...}
  public function set y(value:Number):void{...}
}
```

But every time u access them from within the class or subclass you would need to specify which one u mean, because they have the same name (which is possible as they are in different namepaces). This would look like

```
var before:Number = private::x;
```

or for using the getter:

```
var before:Number = public::x;
```

for protected vars this would even be continued in all subclasses...

People that dont like the underscore could use any other syntax to make the names unique, e.g. capital first letter for getters and setters like in c#.

Answer (score 1):

In Actionscript 2.0, _variable meant it was a built in property for an object.  However, I stopped using Actionscript before 3.0 came out, so for all I know, it could have changed for 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

Simple - _{Your variable name} means that it's private.

In AS3, you define getters and setters like

```
public function get myVar ():String
{
    return _myVar;
}
```

this ends up being transparent outside of the class and showing as

```
myclass.myvar
```

Thus getters and setters in AS3 essentially look like obfuscated properties. So you need some way to differentiate - so you privates start with "_".

Answer (score 0):

I tend to prefix all private variables with "_", even ones without getters or setters. This methodology allows me to know right away when any function is manipulating its private variables while I glance down through code. It seems like a small thing, but it can be quite useful.

Try not to use protected variables unless you absolutely know what you are doing. They are evil. The only reason you would ever use one is to allow subclasses to access variables in the superclass. However, if the value of the protected variable was somehow very important to the superclass, the superclass would never know if the subclass modified it. Better to make it private and provide a protected getter and/or a setter for the subclass, even though it is a little more work. In this way, the superclass can respond to any attempts to change the value.